# Droid's mediaserver dies on camera.takePicture()

Tags: android, android-camera

On Motorola Droid, Firmware 2.1-update1, Kernel 2.9.29-omap1, Build # ESE81

When attempting to take a picture, mediaserver dies with a segmentation 
fault.

I've tried putting `takePicture` in a timer and running it a few seconds after 
camera initialization to check for race conditions, but no change. Just 
calling `Camera.open()` doesn't cause the crash. Also, calling `Camera.open()` 
causes what I think is the autofocus motor to make a sort of ticking sound.

Code that breaks:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public final class ChopperMain extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    try {
        Camera camera = Camera.open();
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        camera.takePicture(
                new Camera.ShutterCallback() {
                    public void onShutter() {
                        ;
                    }
                }, 
                new Camera.PictureCallback() {
                    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                        ;
                    }
                },
                new Camera.PictureCallback() {
                    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                        ;
                    }
                },
            new PictureCallback() {
                public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                    System.out.println("Ta da.");
                }
            }
        });

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}
```

Debug Log:

```
D/CameraHal(10158): CameraSettings constructor
D/CameraHal(10158): CameraHal constructor
D/CameraHal(10158): Model ID: Droid
D/CameraHal(10158): Software ID 2.1-update1
D/dalvikvm(  988): GC freed 2 objects / 56 bytes in 215ms
D/ViewFlipper( 1074): updateRunning() mVisible=false, mStarted=true, mUserPresent=false, mRunning=false
I/HPAndroidHAL(10158): Version 2988.  Build Time: Oct 26 2009:11:21:55.
D/CameraHal(10158): 19 default parameters
D/CameraHal(10158): Immediate Zoom/1:0. Current zoom level/1:0
D/CameraHal(10158): CameraHal constructor exited ok
D/CameraService(10158): Client::Client X (pid 10400)
D/CameraService(10158): CameraService::connect X
D/CameraService(10158): takePicture (pid 10400)
I/DEBUG   (10159): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG   (10159): Build fingerprint: 'verizon/voles/sholes/sholes:2.1-update1/ESE81/29593:user/release-keys'
I/DEBUG   (10159): pid: 10158, tid: 10158  >>> /system/bin/mediaserver <<<
I/DEBUG   (10159): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), fault addr 00000008
I/DEBUG   (10159):  r0 00000000  r1 00000000  r2 a969030c  r3 a9d1bfe0
I/DEBUG   (10159):  r4 00045eb0  r5 0000eb10  r6 000153a0  r7 a9c89fd2
I/DEBUG   (10159):  r8 00000000  r9 00000000  10 00000000  fp 00000000
I/DEBUG   (10159):  ip a969085c  sp bec4fba0  lr a9689c65  pc a9d1bfde  cpsr 60000030
I/DEBUG   (10159):          #00  pc 0001bfde  /system/lib/libutils.so
I/DEBUG   (10159):          #01  pc 00009c62  /system/lib/libcamera.so
I/DEBUG   (10159):          #02  pc 00007b0c  /system/lib/libcameraservice.so
I/DEBUG   (10159):          #03  pc 00021f98  /system/lib/libui.so
I/DEBUG   (10159):          #04  pc 00015514  /system/lib/libbinder.so
I/DEBUG   (10159):          #05  pc 00018dd8  /system/lib/libbinder.so
I/DEBUG   (10159):          #06  pc 00018fa6  /system/lib/libbinder.so
I/DEBUG   (10159):          #07  pc 000087d2  /system/bin/mediaserver
I/DEBUG   (10159):          #08  pc 0000c228  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (10159): 
I/DEBUG   (10159): code around pc:
I/DEBUG   (10159): a9d1bfcc bd1061e3 f7f3b510 bd10e97e 4d17b570 
I/DEBUG   (10159): a9d1bfdc 6886a300 460418ed fff4f7ff d10a4286 
I/DEBUG   (10159): a9d1bfec 46234913 20054a13 f06f1869 18aa040a 
I/DEBUG   (10159): 
I/DEBUG   (10159): code around lr:
I/DEBUG   (10159): a9689c54 e0240412 0204f8d0 050cf104 edf0f7fd 
I/DEBUG   (10159): a9689c64 f7fd4628 f8d4ecf2 b1533204 f852681a 
I/DEBUG   (10159): a9689c74 18581c0c 7101f504 ed82f7fd f8c42000 
I/DEBUG   (10159): 
I/DEBUG   (10159): stack:
I/DEBUG   (10159):     bec4fb60  4000902c  /dev/binder
I/DEBUG   (10159):     bec4fb64  a9d19675  /system/lib/libutils.so
I/DEBUG   (10159):     bec4fb68  00002bb4  
I/DEBUG   (10159):     bec4fb6c  a9d1b26f  /system/lib/libutils.so
I/DEBUG   (10159):     bec4fb70  bec4fbbc  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (10159):     bec4fb74  00095080  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (10159):     bec4fb78  a9c8c028  /system/lib/libcameraservice.so
I/DEBUG   (10159):     bec4fb7c  a9c8c028  /system/lib/libcameraservice.so
I/DEBUG   (10159):     bec4fb80  00015390  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (10159):     bec4fb84  a9c89fd2  /system/lib/libcameraservice.so
I/DEBUG   (10159):     bec4fb88  00045ebc  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (10159):     bec4fb8c  afe0f110  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (10159):     bec4fb90  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (10159):     bec4fb94  afe0f028  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (10159):     bec4fb98  df002777  
I/DEBUG   (10159):     bec4fb9c  e3a070ad  
I/DEBUG   (10159): #00 bec4fba0  00045eb0  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (10159):     bec4fba4  00045ebc  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (10159):     bec4fba8  000153a0  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (10159):     bec4fbac  a9689c65  /system/lib/libcamera.so
I/DEBUG   (10159): #01 bec4fbb0  a9c8c028  /system/lib/libcameraservice.so
I/DEBUG   (10159):     bec4fbb4  00015390  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (10159):     bec4fbb8  000153a0  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (10159):     bec4fbbc  a9c87b0f  /system/lib/libcameraservice.so
I/DEBUG   (10159): debuggerd committing suicide to free the zombie!
I/DEBUG   (10426): debuggerd: Mar 22 2010 17:31:05
W/MediaPlayer( 1021): MediaPlayer server died!
I/ServiceManager(  984): service 'media.audio_flinger' died
I/ServiceManager(  984): service 'media.player' died
I/ServiceManager(  984): service 'media.camera' died
I/ServiceManager(  984): service 'media.audio_policy' died
W/Camera  (10400): Camera server died!
W/Camera  (10400): ICamera died
E/Camera  (10400): Error 100
I/System.out(10400): Camera error, code 100
W/AudioSystem( 1021): AudioFlinger server died!
W/AudioSystem( 1021): AudioPolicyService server died!
I/        (10425): ServiceManager: 0xad08
E/AudioPostProcessor(10425): 
E/AudioPostProcessor(10425): AudioMgr Error:Failed to open gains file /data/ap_gain.bin
E/AudioPostProcessor(10425): 
E/AudioPostProcessor(10425): AudioMgr Error:Failed to  read gains/coeffs from /data 
E/AudioPostProcessor(10425): Audio coeffs init success. 
I/CameraService(10425): CameraService started: pid=10425
D/Audio_Unsolicited(10425): in readyToRun
D/Audio_Unsolicited(10425): Create socket successful 10 
I/AudioFlinger(10425): AudioFlinger's thread 0x11c30 ready to run
E/AudioService( 1021): Media server died.
E/AudioService( 1021): Media server started.
W/AudioPolicyManager(10425): setPhoneState() setting same state 0
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing most of the code necessary to work with a `Camera`. [Here is a sample project](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Camera/Picture/) that is more complete.

Comment: I think by "incomplete" you're referring to the absence of preview code?  I don't actually need any kind of preview for my project, or even to save it to file--I just need to keep it in memory.  Is there a way to safely work with the camera without setting up a preview?  Given that I don't actually need it, it seems like a lot of overhead.

Comment: AFAIK, you need the preview -- it's a requirement for privacy reasons. But I also was referring to setting up the camera parameters (image format, image size, etc.), which the code you have above lacks.

Comment: I did some testing--it looks like you don't need to set parameters (it uses default values if you don't), but you're right about the preview.  Thanks!

Comment: Good to know that the defaults work OK, and good to know that you got your stuff running.

Comment: I got the ANR exception while running that code. I clicked the Take Picture option 2 times. 1st time no issues. But 2nd time I got that error. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: @aasha: You are welcome to click the "Ask Question" button in the upper-right hand corner of the page, ask a question (including pasting the stack trace from the ANR), and submit it. Since this is from one of my open source projects or samples, include the `commonsware` tag (along with `android`), to make sure that I see it.