# Camera Error 100

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm testing my application on Samsung Galaxy Ace, and I get the supported sizes with

```
cameraParams.getSupportedPictureSizes();
```

It works with all of them except of (320 x 240) - the preview turns black and I get this error: `Camera Error 100`

Comment: Colithium: Error 100.  Its the question title :-P

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Camera Error 100 - "Media server died. In this case, the application must release the Camera object and instantiate a new one."

Do what the SDK says and release the camera object and make a new one.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html

Read this, too.  It might help you: [Droid's mediaserver dies on camera.takePicture()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734886/droids-mediaserver-dies-on-camera-takepicture)

Comment: Thanks it worked!! I just had to reload the activity after that

Answer (score 1):

I had error 100 on samsung galaxy s3. The problem in my case was in camera dimensions. I followed android developers camera guide and was setting video size (setVideoSize (widht,height)) in prepareVideoRecorder();

But I was setting wrong dimension what caused camera freeze,crash with error 100 and "camera server died".

The solution is:

adding next two lines

```
   mPreviewHeight = mCamera.getParameters().getPreviewSize().height;
   mPreviewWidth = mCamera.getParameters().getPreviewSize().width;
```

in block (in surfaceChange method):

```
  try {
      mPreviewHeight = mCamera.getParameters().getPreviewSize().height;
      mPreviewWidth = mCamera.getParameters().getPreviewSize().width;

      mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
      mCamera.startPreview();
  } catch (Exception e){
      Log.d(TAG, "Error starting mCamera preview: " + e.getMessage());
  }
```

and then in prepareVideoRecorder() setting this parameters to camera:

```
  mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(mPreviewWidth, mPreviewHeight);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by removing usage or setting the of the Camera parameter:

**setAutoWhiteBalanceLock(false);**

Answer (score 0):

I get the error when i use camera with gLSurfaceView for preview.
I fixed the bug by Comment out

```
//params.setRecordingHint(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the preview format might help in this case. I was setting the preview format as

```
param.setPreviewFormat(ImageFormat.YV12);
```

Removing above line solved the problem for me.