# Camera Error 100 Detail

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, camera-calibration

Can anyone tell me what exactly `Camera Error 100` is?

At the time of taking picture sometimes I am getting it. It happened when I called `camera.takepicutre();` and shutter and raw callback are called, but jpeg-callback is not getting called.

I just want to know what exactly `Camera Error 100` is and when it is generated.
Already saw the original android camera code, but didn't find `Camera Error 100` there.
And this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6837975/camera-error-100), but couldn't find any help. Because most of the time I am able to get the picture, but sometimes I am getting this error.
After seeing the [Android developer site](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#CAMERA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED) they are saying release the camera resource and start a new one. But still didn't able to find the reason behind that?

Comment: @ Durga: Code is bit large that the only reason i asked general thing about Camera Error 100 the reason behind that this error called.

Comment: This might help - https://stackoverflow.com/a/64168613/3551778

Answer (score 1):

maybe you used camera as this order

```
camera.stopPreview();
camera.takePicture(.....);
camera.startPreview();
```

**but that is false.**
you should use it as

```
camera.startPreview();  //ignore it,if you have started it.
camera.takePicture(.....);
camera.startPreview();
```

I have tried it,it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

Camera Error 100 - "Media server died. In this case, the application must release the Camera object and instantiate a new one."