# Android Custom Camera video capture Issue with samsung galaxy tab

Tags: android, android-camera

I am developing a simple custom video recording for my application. When i tried to run the application on Samsung galaxy tab 2 (4.0.4) i got the error "media server died" , "camera server died" ,"I camera died " ,"Camera error 100", and hangs. But it perfectly working on other devices like Toshiba regza , and other custom tabs. Please help me.

Comment: Did you ever get this fixed?

Comment: when i run other custom camera apps from play store i got the same error, so i think the problem is with my device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6837975/camera-error-100) fixes your problem as well.  When dealing with the camera on Android you often have to deal with device specific issues.

Comment: i got the exception when i tried to rotate the camera orientation.